# Set up and remove UIButton text label

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to realize tik tak toe game. So, I have 9 buttons and every time I'm pressing on them they install their text label as "X" or "O"

```
sender.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
// or
sender.setTitle("O", for: .normal)
```

But then , when game is finished , I want to delete all text labels and facing a problem - I can't remove text labels. I've tried several variants and still can't understand problem. I tried :

```
button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.text = ""
button.titleLabel?.text = nil
```

It's not working. Even if I don't see text at this buttons after my "failed reset", text is still set.
Even when I'm doing all variants to delete text and then calling

```
button.titleLabel?.text
```

Im getting not empty line or nil, Im getting "X"!!! (if there was "x" text before)

Comment: your buttons are attached with IBOutlets ? or created programatically ?

Comment: @jawadAli outlet with array of buttons and 1 action

Comment: check your outlets ... they are not connected i guess ... because these all lines should work

Comment: are you doing it on main thread as well ?

Answer (score 2):

i checked it ... these all lines work .. problem is with your connection

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            //self.button.backgroundColor = .red


        }
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I can't understand what's wrong with connection , everything connected. Im beginner , so that's why I don't know what is DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter and how it works

Comment: I've got a function reset , which has for loop

Comment: can you show that function ? and from where it is getting called ?

Comment: in your for loop .. where you are setting button title to nil ... check if button is nil or not

Comment: what does this prints ? `print(button.titleLabel?.text)`

Comment: just for debugging

Comment: whats its output you are getting ?

Comment: nil was just last variant that I tried , empty string didn't help . What do you mean by checking for nil. Here what I`ve got - some title are nil , some are optional https://imgur.com/fbYbsls

Comment: can you send the code via wetransfer ? or come to screen sharing ?

Comment: 9 buttons , those optional values I`ve got after playing one game and then pressing play again button

Comment: tell me your email to send

Comment: l060214@gmail.com

Comment: are you there ?